# Motor is whining but does not agitate

Tags: washer

I bought a GE stack up Washer/Dryer GTUN275EM1WW (now, apparently, [discontinued](http://www.homedepot.com/p/GE-Unitized-Spacemaker-3-4-DOE-cu-ft-Washer-and-5-9-cu-ft-Electric-Dryer-in-White-GTUN275EMWW/203403499)) **3 years ago** and today it stopped working:

- The motor makes the whining noise but it does not agitate the drum during washing and does not rotate it during spinning.
- The water is pumped in and out normally.

Local repairmen say "you bought junk, talk to GE" (over the phone).

GE can send a repairman in 5 days (Diagnostic Fee $108.95 Does Not Include Parts & Labor).

Any suggestions?

Is there a chance that it's something trivial (e.g., a belt fell off)?

Comment: Belt may have broken or come off the pulley. Worth a look before you call.

Comment: Could be a direct drive and the coupler is gone, could be the drive block worn out, could be the tub clutch/brake mechanism is broke. Could be a bad motor. The sound of the motor would help. To me whining is that it's not doing anything or struggling (belt slip), a whirring like it's spinning is different. A hum is different. It could also be a stick transmission. In parts, a belt is about $25, drive block setup about $35, motor or transmission about $200 each. If you are mechanically inclined and into DIY, start with water off, run a cycle empty and watch or listen to the motor area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turned out the belt fell off!
Removed the front panel, put the belt back on, still works fine.

Comment: This might be a new record - 4 years from question to report of successful solution!